# Where clause on column with datatype array<bigint>

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have two tables : Product and Impressions which looks as follows.

```
Product (Product column is string type, Category is of type array<bigint> )

| Product | Category | 
|  ABC    | [1234]   | 
|  AAA    | [3457]   |
|  BGC    | [1234]   |

Impressions (Product > string, Impressions > Int)

| Products | Impressions |
| AAA      | 200         |
| ABD      | 659         |
| ABC      | 298         |
```

To get the Category mapping with impressions and filter the impressions for category = [1234] I'm joining the two tables on column Product as follows

```
Select 
a.Product, 
a.category,
b.Products,
b.Impressions 
from Product a
left join Impressions b
on a.Product = b.Products 
where a.category = [1234]
```

However, it throws an error as it's not allowing me to filter on category which is of type array

Here's how the joined table should look like

```
| Product | Category | Impressions|
| ABC     | [1234]   | 298        |
| BGC     | [1234]   | 0          |
```

What is the solution for this? Appreciate help.

Comment: your sample data does not match data storage protection. If you have a set of multiple elements, this means that each element has a string

Comment: example : ABC 1 ABC 2  ABC 3 ABC 4  AAA 3 AAA 4 AAA 5 AAA 6 AAA 7 .... 
UNDERSTOOD ?

Answer (score 0):

To create an array in Presto/Trino you can use `array[elemetn1, element2, ..]`:

```sql
-- sample data
with Product (Product, Category) as(
    values    ('ABC', array[bigint '1234']),
    ('AAA', array[bigint '3457']),
    ('BGC', array[bigint '1234'])
),
    Impressions (Product, Impressions) as (
        values ('AAA', 200),
        ('ABD', 659),
        ('ABC', 298)
    )

-- query
Select
a.Product,
a.category,
b.Product,
b.Impressions
from Product a
left join Impressions b
on a.Product = b.Product
where a.category = array[1234]; -- here
```

Output:

| Product | category | Product | Impressions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | [1234] | ABC | 298 |
| BGC | [1234] | NULL | NULL |

Also you can consider comparing first element in array i.e. `where a.category[1] = 1234` or better [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) like `contains` - `where contains(a.category, 1234)`

Comment: Thanks @Guru Stron. Executing this query in Athena and there is an error. The error says 'Queries of this type are not supported'

Comment: @iprof0214 what engine version (this was checked against latest Trino version, so there can be lag.in Athena)? Also try other suggestions, like `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked for me in Athena

```
Select
a.Product,
a.category,
b.Product,
b.Impressions
from Product a
left join Impressions b
on a.Product = b.Product
where contains(category,1234)
```

Comment: JIC this is also suggested in my answer)